# Contract extension with short deadline

Tags: job-search

Company A (my current company) offered me a contract extension. I had a 1-year contract and they offered me another year. I am waiting news from company B which may offer me a permanent contract with much higher salary (way too high to negotiate the same conditions with A). However, company A gave me 2 days to accept the extension.

Company B is clearly my preferred option, but the extension from A is the only offer that I have on the table, as for now.

Termination notice at A is 30 days, but I wouldn’t feel very comfortable in quitting after signing the extension (it wouldn’t be loyal and wouldn’t reflect well on me). On the other hand, B would be a huge step forward for my career.

I would like to receive suggestions on how to deal with this situation.

Comment: If it was just about that, B would be an easy choice. However, there are other ways in which things could go south. I work in a quite narrow (hence, a small world) area of research in which who is writing recommendation letters makes a difference. Worst case scenario, sure not an unlikely one, is that some candidate had the same PhD advisor as the hiring manager.

Answer (score 1):

You look after number one, which is you. These companies are likely very good at looking after themselves, you don’t have to look after them.

So you sign with A, wait for company B to sign with them, and if that fails, A is none the wiser.